# Use of safe arguments in android navigation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-safe-args

Is safeArgs plugin used for passing data or we can simply use it for navigation (even when we donot want to pass any data to the destination)? ... I have used navigation Component and safeArgs plugin but my question is should we use the safeArgs plugin just for simply navigating to a new fragment or use it only when we need to navigate with Passing a data ? please can someone help me understand this .... thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#safeargs):

> The recommended way to navigate between destinations is to use the Safe Args Gradle plugin. This plugin generates simple object and builder classes that enable type-safe navigation between destinations. Safe Args is recommended **both for navigating as well as passing data between destinations.**

So it is recommended to always use Safe Args, whether you are passing data or not.

Comment: so it means .... suppose I have a DESTINATION fragment B and it accepts argument of type custom parcelable  and it is nullable argument..... and fragments A and C both navigate to fragment B... Now if I want to send data and navigate to Fragment B from A I can do it easily by using the SafeArgs plugin.. but suppose Fragment C navigates to Fragment B but I donot need to pass any thing to the destination fragment(Fragment B) .. so :  1. Is it better to navigate from C to B with action Id only ??? or 2. shall I pass "null" and use to safe Args to navigate from C to B . please clarify sir . please

Comment: If you add a `defaultValue` (say with `android:defaultValue="@null"` as mentioned on [Safe Args documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types)), then the argument becomes optional, which seems like exactly what your C to B action needs.